# print_r - limit the results to 10?

Tags: php, mysql

Is there a way to limit the print_r to only 3 results?

```
$result = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT host) as host FROM bitnami_wordpress.sss1_latest WHERE CLIENT ='$current_user->user_login' LIMIT 3");

print_r('<div style="color:#fff;text-align:left;font-weight:500;font-size:12px">Target: ' . $result . '</div>');
```

Basically I want to process/display the first 10 results only

```
host
10.1.1.1
10.1.1.2
10.1.1.3
10.1.1.4
10.1.1.5
10.1.1.6
```

My desired output

```
10.1.1.1,10.1.1.2,10.1.1.3...
```

I did tried to add `LIMIT 3` in my MySQL statement but no output.

Thanks!
Nathalie

Comment: ```array_chunk``` is your friend.

Comment: I would argue [`array_slice`](http://www.php.net/array_slice) is a better friend here. But even better would be to use the right SQL directly. We'd need to know more about the schema to help.

Comment: I assume that `GROUP_CONCAT()` is causing the problem, it is making the list of IP's into a single value (hence the LIMIT 3 isn't working).

Comment: True Jeto. I should just stop today, as I only give bad advice I feel like.. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Using `LIMIT` with `GROUP_CONCAT()` won't really work, since `GROUP_CONCAT()` will return one row.

Instead, use a sub-select as shown here.

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(host) FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT host 
    FROM bitnami_wordpress.sss1_latest 
    WHERE CLIENT ='$current_user->user_login' 
    LIMIT 3
) AS hosts;
```

- [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ef9eca5/4)